# Run R script with the start up of R

Tags: r, centos

I just want to run an R script `example.r` automatically when I start R
I am using `R version 3.2.3` on `centOS`

I searched for this but I couldn't figure that out.

Comment: You can add source("example.R") in your ~r installation path~/etc/rprofile.site

Comment: can you please explain more?

Comment: Where did you install your R? Go to that folder. Open a folder called etc inside that folder. inside the etc folder there is a file called rprofile.site. This file is sourced when r starts up

Comment: i went to /usr/lib64/R/etc/,,,,,,, and the files i found there are ,,,,,,,,javaconf  ldpaths  Makeconf  Renviron  repositories

Comment: You may need to create the file if it does not already exist. From your terminal, `echo 'source("/path/to/example.r")' >> /usr/lib64/R/etc/Rprofile.site`, assuming you have sufficient permissions.

Comment: thank you @nrussell that's super clear ,, but is /usr/lib64/R is the default directory for R ? or maybe i went to the wrong dirc.?

Comment: On CentOS 7 it should be because that particular distribution is only available in 64-bit (i.e. it would not be in `/usr/lib/R`). If you hadn't previously created that file, it won't exist, but that is expected. From the help file: *"[...] ‘R_HOME/etc/Rprofile.site’, which is used if it exists (which it does not in a ‘factory-fresh’ installation)"*. You can always check the location of R by running `Sys.getenv("R_HOME")` in an R session.

Comment: @nrussell thank you it's work just fine now, i would accepted as an answer

Comment: @nrussell can you please check my other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36935348/installation-of-package-forecast-had-non-zero-exit-status

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The startup behavior of R can be modified by editing `Rprofile.site`, which may need to be created, as the default R installation does not do this for you automatically. On CentOS 7, this file should be located in the directory  `/usr/lib64/R/etc/`; or more generally `$R_HOME/etc/`, where `R_HOME` can be determined by running `Sys.getenv("R_HOME")` from an R session.

For example, if I modify my `Rprofile.site` as follows,

```
[nathan@xxx] cat /tmp/example.r
x <- 1.5
y <- 2.5
z <- 3.5
t <- Sys.time()

[nathan@xxx] cat /usr/lib64/R/etc/Rprofile.site
options(prompt = "R> ")
options(continue = "  ")
options(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
options(scipen = 4)

source("/tmp/example.r")
```

the changes will be reflected in a new R session:

[image]

---

Although apparently not necessary in this example, it is customary to wrap such code in `.First <- function() { ... }` to ensure that it is run immediately upon session startup:

```
[nathan@xxx] cat /usr/lib64/R/etc/Rprofile.site
options(prompt = "R> ")
options(continue = "  ")
options(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
options(scipen = 4)

.First <- function() {
    source("/tmp/example.r")
}
```