# Installation of package ‘forecast’ had non-zero exit status

Tags: r, centos, package

With `R version 3.2.3 (2015-12-10)` on `centOS` I am trying to `install.packages('forecast')`

I get this:

> install.packages('forecast')
>   Installing package into ‘/usr/lib64/R/library’
>   (as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
>   also installing the dependency ‘RcppArmadillo’
>
> trying URL 'http://mirrors.ebi.ac.uk/CRAN/src/contrib/RcppArmadillo_0.6.700.3.0.tar.gz'
>
> ## Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 1002967 bytes (979 KB)
>
> downloaded 979 KB
>
> trying URL 'http://mirrors.ebi.ac.uk/CRAN/src/contrib/forecast_7.1.tar.gz'
>
> ## Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 196896 bytes (192 KB)
>
> downloaded 192 KB
>
> Error in plota.theme(col.border = rgb(68, 68, 68, maxColorValue = 255),  :
>     could not find function "rgb"
>   Calls: source ... eval -> eval -> plota.theme.green.orange -> plota.theme
>   Execution halted
>   Error in plota.theme(col.border = rgb(68, 68, 68, maxColorValue = 255),  :
>     could not find function "rgb"
>   Calls: source ... eval -> eval -> plota.theme.green.orange -> plota.theme
>   Execution halted
>
> The downloaded source packages are in
>           ‘/tmp/Rtmp0jOTCu/downloaded_packages’
>   Updating HTML index of packages in '.Library'
>   Making 'packages.html' ... done
>   Warning messages:
>   1: In install.packages("forecast") :
>     installation of package ‘RcppArmadillo’ had non-zero exit status
>   2: In install.packages("forecast") :
>     installation of package ‘forecast’ had non-zero exit status

I tried every solution to fix this like install package from source indicate the `dependency = TRUE`, etc., but nothing works.

sessionInfo()  give this output

> R version 3.2.3 (2015-12-10)
>   Platform: x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu (64-bit)
>   Running under: CentOS release 6.7 (Final)
>
> locale:
>    [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C
>    [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8
>    [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8
>    [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C
>    [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C
>   [11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C
>
> attached base packages:
>   [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base

Comment: Have you tried installing `RcppArmadillo` via `install.packages("RcppArmadillo")`?

Comment: @RomanLuštrik ..In install.packages("RcppArmadillo") :                                                                                                                                                                             
  installation of package ‘RcppArmadillo’ had non-zero exit status

Comment: Maybe relevant post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25721884

Comment: @zx8754 i tried every single answer in that post .

Comment: Your error message simply state that something went wrong. It is absolutely impossible to know *what* went wrong, if you don't give more information. There must be other error messages that you get before the two that you posted. Add them to your post.

Comment: @Stibu i edited my post can you please check it out.

Comment: @Emad Can you add the output of `sessionInfo()` to your question?

Comment: @nrussell added it ,, thank you for coming

Comment: What happens when you evaluate `rgb(0, 0, 0)`?

Comment: @Stibu       `> rgb(0, 0, 0)                                                                                                                                                                                                     
[1] "#000000" `

Comment: What were the error messages generated from the failed RcppArmadillo installation specifically (I'm assuming the `could not find function "rgb"` errors were generated from a different package)?

Comment: Also, what does `g++ --version` return from your terminal?

Comment: @nrussell the installation of the packages `RcppArmadillo ,forecast,Rcpp ` are generating the same error messages

Comment: @nrussell  the output of `g++ --version` is   `g++ (GCC) 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-16)   `

Comment: It may have to do with the fact that CentOS 6 has a fairly old toolchain, as discussed in [this issue](https://github.com/RcppCore/RcppArmadillo/issues/85). You could try installing an older version of RcppArmadillo [from here](https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/RcppArmadillo/), maybe something in the 0.4.500 range. I don't have a CentOS 6 machine available so I'm not sure what the latest compatible version is for that OS.

Comment: @nrussell i tried to install defferent  older versions with the command `install.packages("http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/RcppArmadillo/RcppArmadillo_0.2.4.tar.gz", repos=NULL)` but still not working

Comment: @nrussell first you were right i needed an old version of forecast and all it's dependencies ,, but i couldn't install them because of the script i was runing at the runtime of R ( as we did it in the previous question ) so i deleted them and everything goes fine ,,,,

Answer (score 0):

On UBUNTU 18.04 I got the following

Configuration failed because libcurl was not found. Try installing:
 * deb: libcurl4-openssl-dev (Debian, Ubuntu, etc)
 * rpm: libcurl-devel (Fedora, CentOS, RHEL)
 * csw: libcurl_dev (Solaris)

I installed the package libcurl14-openssl-dev using synaptic, that solved the problem.

Answer (score -3):

Install devtools. Most of the time the problem in installing R packages is that these tools are not there. Once this is installed, the zero exit error goes away.

```
install.packages('devtools')
```

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-r-packages-using-devtools-on-ubuntu-16-04