# Errors during installation of R dependencies after new R installation on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: r, ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04, forecast

**System:** Ubuntu 18.04

**Original error that showed up that prompted me to try to reinstall R and dependencies:**

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for 'lubridate' in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):  unable to load shared object '/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/stringi/libs/stringi.so':   libicui18n.so.57: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

**Steps to reproduce:**

1. Install R: `apt install r-base`
2. Try to install R dependencies: `install.packages(c("dplyr", "lubridate", "qcc", "forecast"), repos='http://cran.us.r-project.org')`

**Error that displays during installation:**

```
/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/BH/include/boost/smart_ptr/scoped_ptr.hpp:74:31: warning: 'template<class> class std::auto_ptr' is deprecated
```

**Error that displays after installation:**

```
The downloaded source packages are in
    '/tmp/RtmpnulsEe/downloaded_packages'
Warning message:
In install.packages(c("dplyr", "lubridate", "qcc", "forecast", "stringi"),  :
  installation of package 'forecast' had non-zero exit status
```

**After purging and reinstalling `r-base` and R dependencies, I'm seeing this...(already checked that `libcurl4-openssl-dev` was latest version):**

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for 'forecast' in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...): 
unable to load shared object '/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/curl/libs/curl.so':
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4: version `CURL_OPENSSL_3' not found (required by /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/curl/libs/curl.so)
```

**Update:** Apparently it's something in the `forecast` library, because I reproduced that error like this:

```
$ R
> library(forecast)
Error: package or namespace load failed for 'forecast' in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
 unable to load shared object '/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/curl/libs/curl.so':
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4: version `CURL_OPENSSL_3' not found (required by /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/curl/libs/curl.so)
```

Comment: I've been having this problem a lot lately... with most of the packages, installing `devtools` and then doing the install from github, e.g. `devtools::install_github("tidyverse/lubridate")` works.

Comment: That's a circular argument. OP says "help me I cannot install from source" and you say "here install from source".  Does not help him overcome build-dependencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**After trying the following (purging and reinstalling R between each step):**

1. `apt purge r-base`
2. Added/removed several different PPAs before realizing none of them supported Bionic Beaver. Result: `Release not found`.
3. Found Michael Rutter's PPA and attempted to use that. Result: same error message from above (`'CURL_OPENSSL_3' not found`).
4. Attempting several solutions to this [SO article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36935348/installation-of-package-forecast-had-non-zero-exit-status). Result: same error message from above (`'CURL_OPENSSL_3' not found`).
5. Read [this article](https://community.rstudio.com/t/error-version-curl-openssl-3-not-found/8090) and performed the following in R:

   ```
   > remove.packages("curl")
   > install.packages("curl")
   > install.packages(c("dplyr", "lubridate", "qcc", "forecast", "stringi", "curl"), repos='http://cran.us.r-project.org')
   ```

And everything worked as intended.

Comment: The last step could use binary for `r-cran-dplyr`, `r-cran-lubridate`, ...

Answer (score 3):

Your original problem is that `stringi` was built against a *distro package* version of `libicu` which changed. As this distribution package does not know you have `lubridate` in /usr/local it changes and breaks things.

There are a number of ways to fix this. The easiest (and narrowest) is to make sure you have `libicu-dev` installed.  You could then reinstall (ie: rebuild `stringi`) after which `lubridate` will load.

For the rest you are just going somewhat wild throwing everything that is moveable up against the wall.  You need to take a moment to realize that you can *either* install all these *as binaries* (ie from the Michael Rutter PPAs at launchpad), or from source. Your call.  I have an older answer explaining the difference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2170043/r-apt-get-install-r-cran-foo-vs-install-packagesfoo/2170103#2170103) (as well as in other follow-ups here) and we help on the `r-sig-debian` list too.

But in short: read this [README at CRAN](https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/README.html) (esp first few paragraphs) and consider the PPAs.

Comment: Interesting... this was how I originally had installed R (through PPAs) which wasn't working, thus the attempt to install through distro. Let me try it again after another purge and see if I can get it working correctly.

Comment: Now I remember why I couldn't use PPA: `Get:10 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [83.2 kB]
Err:11 https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic/ Release    
  404  Not Found [IP: 52.84.243.137 443]
Reading package lists... Done                                       
E: The repository 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic/ Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.`

Comment: I can't seem to find a CRAN mirror / PPA that supports Bionic, except the Michael Rutter PPA (`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:marutter/rrutter`), but I'm still getting errors when attempting to install R or the libraries...

Comment: There are two: one for R 3.5 itself (https://launchpad.net/~marutter/+archive/ubuntu/rrutter3.5) and then one with packages (https://launchpad.net/~marutter/+archive/ubuntu/c2d4u). See Michael's blog for more (http://rubuntu.netlify.com/).