# How to load all my functions in my project automatically in R

Tags: r

I am writing more than 6 functions and save them in my R.project. Every time, to start working using my project, I need to run each function manually one by one. Is there a way that I can load all these functions automatically?

Comment: Create a package and then you need to load only the package

Comment: @akrun can I extend my project automatically to a package.

Comment: Thank you @akrun so much for your comment.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Create your own package and load it on the start-up, you will have all the function available. [A tutorial](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/Leisch-CreatingPackages.pdf)
2. Customize R start-up loading automatically your R files containing your functions. [A tutorial](https://www.r-bloggers.com/fun-with-rprofile-and-customizing-r-startup/) and [an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36914701/run-r-script-with-the-start-up-of-r)

Comment: Thanks so much for your great help.

Answer (score 1):

We can create a package in `R`

1. Bundle the functions and create a package -`yourpackage` and then load the package

   ```
   library(yourpackage)
   ```
2. One example is [here](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200486488-Developing-Packages-with-RStudio)
3. Another resource is [here](https://hilaryparker.com/2014/04/29/writing-an-r-package-from-scratch/)
4. Yet another is [here](http://kbroman.org/pkg_primer/pages/build.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't wish to take the package approach (which I agree is the best approach), you could stack all your functions on top of one another in an R script and source it on startup. One step instead of 6. End up with all the functions in your .GlobalEnv

Put this in an R script:

```
###Put in a script
eeee <- function(){
  cat("yay I'm a function")
}


ffff <- function(){
  cat("Aaaaaah a talking function")
}
```

If you use RStudio, the code would be as below. Otherwise change the source location. Do this in console (or in a script):

```
###Do this
source('~/.active-rstudio-document')
```

Then you can do:

```
eeee()
yay I'm a function

ffff()
Aaaaaah a talking function
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run the below script before starting your work:

```
source_code_dir <- "./R/"  #The directory where all source code files are saved.
file_path_vec <- list.files(source_code_dir, full.names = T)
for(f_path in file_path_vec){source(f_path)}
```