# How to automatically set an option when RStudio starts?

Tags: r, rstudio

I would like to automatically run the following command every time RStudio starts with Windows 10:
`options(browser = "C:/Program Files/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe")`

How should I do it? Is it possible to do it? I tried to put this command in a .Rprofile file. However it did not work. Thanks for your help.

I believe it is a problem of RStudio. Somehow RStudio avoid using my .Rprofile file. If I use RGUI.exe, everything is fine.

Comment: refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36914701/run-r-script-with-the-start-up-of-r

Comment: I believe it is a problem of RStudio. Somehow RStudio avoid using my .Rprofile file.

Comment: check this: https://community.rstudio.com/t/changing-the-default-web-browser-used-in-rstudio/23653

Comment: Thanks Jose. So, basically, I cannot do that with RStudio.